# The type 'HttpRequestMessage' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: visual-studio, azure-pipelines

When i build locally it works, but my VSTS hosted 2017 instance build fails with the following message:

```
[error]apps\Ascend.Identity\AccountController.cs(126,17): Error CS0012: The type 'HttpRequestMessage' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

Locally, there is also a yellow triangle in the reference list.
[image]

but it still builds

and the reference is there in csproj

[image]

and the package is restored from nuget (packages.config)

```
 <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.3" targetFramework="net472" />
```

Comment: The hintpath looks wrong to me.

Comment: If you map your project to a new workspace from TFS and build it locally, how's the result?

Answer (score 2):

In your local, try the steps below:

1. Delete `packages` folder in your source directory.
2. Remove `System.Net.Http` reference.
3. Right click `References`, select `Manage Nuget Packages`, browser and install package `System.Net.Http`.
4. Build your project and check the result. Make sure there is no yellow triangle in the reference list.
5. Check in the changes and queue a build.

Comment: similar issue, I solved by following this thread https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/26131#issuecomment-396753264